# Laravel Livewire Autofill Input Box Based On Drop Down Selection

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I am asking for help. Is there any way I could fill an input box based on drop down selection? On my modal I have a dropdown option for subject description and I would like the subject number input field dynamically change its value. Any help would be much appreciated.

This is how I retrieved the data for my dropdown

```
subjects=DB::table('programs_subj')->select('corsdes', 'corsno')->get()
```

---

This is my dropdown code for the subject description which is working and the selected is saved but I could quite how to incorporate the subject number

```
   <select name="corsdes" id="corsdes" wire:model="corsdes">
          <option value="corsdes" wire:model="corsdes"></option>
          @foreach($subjects as $sbj)
          <option value="{{ $sbj->corsdes }}">{{ $sbj->corsdes}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
<input name="corsno" id="corsno" wire:model="corsno"><input>
```

Comment: You need to fetch where you save it id table fectch and then you need to put if conditional and control selected like @if($sbj->cordes === $item->id) selected @endif into the option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have the public properties $corsdes and $corsno then:

```
public function updatedCorsdes($value)
{
   $this->corsno = $this->subjects->where('corsdes',$value)->first()->corsno;
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro, its working. I just replaced the $this->subjects to DB::table('my_table') since I am using DB Facade. Thanks Again